# What is the "total count" metric in Android Studio's Memory Profiler?

Tags: android-studio, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm unable to find a description of this metric anywhere in the Android developer documentation. Here is a link to what I've most recently looked at: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

Here's what I *think* it is: the number of objects in the heap that have not been deallocated.

Please, if possible, provide a credible resource that supports your reasoning (e.g. a Google I/0 talk on Youtube with a minute-mark or some Android documentation).

EDIT: Here is a screenshot that includes the metric. [image]

Comment: Could you supplement the question with a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot added as requested.

Answer (score 2):

### Total Count column

`Total Count` is defined as the total object count (see [Android Studio source](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/profilers-ui/src/com/android/tools/profilers/memory/MemoryClassifierView.java#L150)), specifically:

```
  new AttributeColumn<>(
    "Total Count",
    () -> new SimpleColumnRenderer<ClassifierSet>(
      value -> Integer.toString(value.getAdapter().getTotalObjectCount()),
      value -> null,
      SwingConstants.RIGHT),
```

This `getTotalObjectCount()` [is defined as](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/profilers/src/com/android/tools/profilers/memory/adapters/ClassifierSet.java#L86):

```
  public int getTotalObjectCount() {
    return mySnapshotObjectCount + myDeltaAllocations - myDeltaDeallocations;
  }
```

---

### Incrementing methods

The `mySnapshotObjectCount` value is incremented inside [`addSnapshotInstanceObject`](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/profilers/src/com/android/tools/profilers/memory/adapters/ClassifierSet.java#L122), which has the helpful comment:

> Add an instance to the baseline snapshot and update the accounting of
>   the "total" values.

The `myDeltaAllocations` and `myDeltaDeallocations` values are incremented [inside `addDeltaInstanceInformation`](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/profilers/src/com/android/tools/profilers/memory/adapters/ClassifierSet.java#L193):

```
if (isAllocation) {
  myDeltaAllocations++;
}
else {
  myDeltaDeallocations++;
}
```

This is called [inside `partition`](https://github.com/JetBrains/android/blob/master/profilers/src/com/android/tools/profilers/memory/adapters/ClassifierSet.java#L526), which contains the helpful comment:

> Partitions `InstanceObjects` in `snapshotInstances` and `myDeltaInstances` according to the current `ClassifierSet` strategy. This will consume the instances from the input.

This `snapshotInstance` is the same one used to increment `mySnapshotInstanceObjectCount`, thus showing that all 3 values are very closely linked, are created when a partition (snapshot) is made, and all factor into the Total Count.

---

### Final formula

So, the final answer is:

```
Total Count = Snapshot objects + New allocations - New deallocations
```

- Snapshot objects = number of object instances allocated before the snapshot.
- New allocations = number of allocations during snapshot.
- New deallocations = number of deallocations during snapshot.

This definition of the equation matches what Axifive stated in another answer, and the linked video.

Comment: Fantastic work! Could you also provide explanations backed up by source code for `Snapshot objects`, `New allocations`, and `New deallocations` in your answer? I trust that you've done your research but I would like to leave my bountied faith with a full, pedantically-written proof when it comes to a source-code backed answer like yours, and I don't trust myself to fully comprehend the source code on my own.

Comment: @GrantPark Sure. I've added info on how all 3 are incremented, as well as the connection between them. If I go further I fear I'll just be explaining the code line by line, but let me know any other areas that need improving! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: So seeing where these methods are called as well as the relevant comments are helpful, but I would like to know how these items are being calculated e.g. does the `snapshot objects` count incorporate the deallocation count of the object before the snapshot? That said, I sincerely appreciate your time in digging through the profiler source code -- it makes for a strong answer considering that there is no proper documentation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's just the number of objects (so allocations / deallocations aren't included), but not confident enough on that to include in the answer. I'll have a further look when I get back from work!

Answer (score 0):

> Here's what I think it is: the number of objects in the heap that have
>   not been deallocated.

You are right with your thinking but I cannot serve you with a public thread for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the total number of instance, that has allocated before the selected period + memory allocation for the selected period (or as you says: number of objects(instances) in the heap that haven't been deallocated for the selected period)

You can see this [here](https://youtu.be/O5V9ZSL0BsM?t=459)

On the Instance View, it can be seen that three `int` arrays were allocated at 1m, but not deallocated (for the selected period).